# C#: x86-x64 memory model vs ECMA

Tags: c#, concurrency, x86-64

I've read a lot about differences between x86-x64, ARM, ECMA memory models for C#. What is the real world's best practice: developing according with stronger x86-x64 model or with weaker ECMA? Should I consider possible reordering, stale values, safe publishing for applications run only on x86-x64 hardware?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I've read a lot about differences between x86-x64, ARM, ECMA memory models for C#. What is the real world's best practice: developing according with stronger x86-x64 model or with weaker ECMA? Should I consider possible reordering, stale values, safe publishing for applications run only on x86-x64 hardware?

The best practice is to write your code so that it is *correct*.

I choose to write correct code by *not writing multithreaded shared memory code*.  That's what I would encourage you to do as well.

If you must write multithreaded shared memory code then I would recommend that you use high-level libraries such as the Task Parallel Library, rather than trying to understand the complexities of the memory model.

If you want to write low-level shared memory multithreaded code that is correct only on strong memory models, well, I can't stop you, but that seems like an enormous amount of work to go to in order to create a program that has subtle bugs when you try to run it on ARM.